# How can I Create a CMS using php where end user doesn't have to know anything about database. Is that possible

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system, mysqli

In genera sense if  I create a CMS using php .Where I created and named the database in my localhost. Now if I or my clent upload the CMS in any server how will it work. because there is no database in that server.

And in my php code I wrote to create database. Now how can i create a CMS which can automatically create database and tables where client doesn't have to know about anything besides uploading the CMS.

Example:
In the CMS there is a query saying (SELECT * FROM users). I named the table users which contains user information.

but If a client upload my CMS into his server how will it work. Does he have to go phpmyadmin and create a identical database like I created and named while developing the CMS.

Comment: are you intending to develop a product that requires a installer for automatic installation?

Comment: are you saying you dont want to depend on a database server? if so, sqlite may be the way to go

Comment: If no database has been activated on the hosting provider, no way you could create it anyway, unless your CMS doesn't take root access to the server and install/configure the database. I mean, you can't ship your CMS with a database installer. But as @looneydoodle sayd, PHP ships with SQLlite since v. 5+, so you can always fall back to that

Answer (score 0):

You can create a php page that will execute some queries to create the database and tables.

- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_db.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

But I think, it would be a good choice to ask your user to create a database(blank database) and provide the details of the `hostname`, `database name`, `database username` and `database password`, to your CMS system. So you could use this to execute the queries for creating the tables. I think, that's how most of the forums and CMS softwares do.

Comment: That wouldn't work, no host gives the Apache/www user the rights to create a whole database. The only way is for the phisical user to acquire the rights to have a database from the host, who creates it and usually creates a database user who doesn't have the right privileges to create *another* database (even because they cost money)